# Create a new Object Instance of Existing object dart

Tags: flutter, dart

So I basically have following problem in my code:

I have a set to that I add my Object:

```
  ProductInstance p = ProductInstance("name", 3);

  products.add(p);
```

then I modify the object & and execute a method with it:

```
   p.zahl = 5;

  addProduct(p);
```

The methods then prints both values out and because of Object References its the same :/

```
addProduct(ProductInstance product) {
  ProductInstance? temp;

  if (products.isNotEmpty) {
    for (var element in products) {
      if (true) {
        temp = element;
      }
    }
    if (temp != null) {
      print(temp.zahl);
      print(product.zahl);
    }
  }

  if (products.isEmpty) {
    products.add(product);
  }
}
```

So what I want to do is to pass a new Instance of the existing p in my method without a lot of refactoring. What can I do?

Full Code to achieve same behaviour:

```
main() {
  ProductInstance p = ProductInstance("name", 3);

  products.add(p);

  p.zahl = 5;

  addProduct(p);
}

Set products = {};

class ProductInstance {
  String name;
  int zahl;

  ProductInstance(this.name, this.zahl);
}

addProduct(ProductInstance product) {
  ProductInstance? temp;

  if (products.isNotEmpty) {
    for (var element in products) {
      if (true) {
        temp = element;
      }
    }
    if (temp != null) {
      print(temp.zahl);
      print(product.zahl);
    }
  }

  if (products.isEmpty) {
    products.add(product);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using the `=` operator on two objects they are both going to point to the same object.

Also when you change the value inside with `p.zahl = 5;` you are also changing its value inside the set of products. I do not fully understand what you want to do but here is a way you can print 2 different values. You will also need to declare a setter value , as depicted below

```
main() {
  ProductInstance p = ProductInstance("name", 3);

  products.add(p);
  //p.zahl = 5; dont change the value here

  addProduct(p);
}

Set products = {};

class ProductInstance {
  String name;
  int zahl;

  set setZahl(int k) {
    zahl = k;
  }

  ProductInstance(this.name, this.zahl);
}

addProduct(ProductInstance product) {
  ProductInstance? temp;

  if (products.isNotEmpty) {
    for (var element in products) {
      if (true) {
        temp = ProductInstance(element.name, element.zahl +2); //create a new object
        
      }
    }
    if (temp != null) {
      print(temp.zahl);
      print(product.zahl);
    }
  }

  if (products.isEmpty) {
    products.add(product);
  }
}
```